# Is there a word for the letter that a diacritic is applied to?

Tags: terminology, diacritics

If I am speaking about a letter that has a diacritical mark (e.g. 'á'), what word or phrase should I use to reference the base letter (e.g. 'a')? I'm looking for something a little more concise than "the letter that it modifies" or "the letter that it is added to". I couldn't find anything helpful from Googling, and a cursory look through the [Wikipedia article on diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) didn't reveal any usage of such a word.

Comment: Character? grapheme?

Comment: @Mary Those work well for letters in general, but I'm looking for something specific to the context of diacritics.

Comment: The modified letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct term for this in Unicodese is ***grapheme base***.

Note that characters which are respectively considered *diacritic, non-spacing combining mark*, and *grapheme extend* characters are all slightly different.  It would take a Venn diagram to show the overlap, though.

See  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21777744/471272), its answers, and the standards documents referenced therein.

Comment: Should *combing mark* be *combining mark*?